# Custom tableView cell with parallax scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to do next task: in my app I have 1 tableView with 4 custom cells. At drag down, first cell should stretch and his content need to be always at center. When i lift finger, cell returns at its standard size. The same thing with last one, when the bottom of the tableView is reached, last cell should stretch. I found many solutions, but all of them are explained how to do this with the bottom of table, but not with cell. I need to do this programmatically, any help will be great.

Examples that i found:

1) https://github.com/BillCarsonFr/ScrollviewParallax

2) https://github.com/nrj/StretchyHeaderCollectionViewLayout